# SimpleCursoradapater throwing error?

Tags: android, sqlite

hi the cursor adapter is throwing error that constructor is not defined ?

```
String[] from = { "hour", "minute" };

        int[] to = { android.R.id.text1,android.R.id.text2 };

        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.activity_list_item, getAlarm, from, to);
```

and the error is as follows

```
The constructor SimpleCursorAdapter(MyDatabaseHelper, int, Cursor, String[], int[]) is undefined    MyDatabaseHelper.java
```

Comment: Am I the only one here thinking people should at least read method signature before posting such questions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is Context in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(YourActivityName.this,
            android.R.layout.activity_list_item, getAlarm, from, to, CursorAdapter.NO_SELECTION);
```

You can use any other flags instead of CursorAdapter.NO_SELECTION if you want.